# JAVA - Can't Fetch Image in database (mysql)

Tags: java, mysql, blob, bufferedimage

Back then, I successfully manipulated my webcam through webcam-capture library.
Here is my code :

```
public void capture() {
    wc.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.QVGA.getSize());
    WebcamPanel wp = new WebcamPanel(wc);
    wp.setMirrored(true);
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    tp.setSize(jp.getWidth(), jp.getHeight());
    tp.addTab("", wp);
    tp.getParent().revalidate();
}
```

And it happen that I want to save the capture image into my database (mysql),
the good thing is that I able to save it successfully.
With this codes:

```
public void save() {
    BufferedImage bi = wc.getImage();
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bimg = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bi, "JPG", bimg);
        byte[] imgb = bimg.toByteArray();

        try {
            Blob bis = conn.createBlob();
            bis.setBytes(1, imgb);
            String query = "insert into tbl_img (imgid,clientimg) values ('" + but.getText() + "' , '" + bis + "')";
            psmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            psmt.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success", "Capture", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

From BufferedImage I converted it ByteArray to fit into the mysql Blob flag.
As oppose of  inserting data, I want to retrieve it back as image and put it in the JLabel through JFrame directly. Shall we say without occupying some space in the Hard Drive.

I have a code for retrieving image but the result seems a white JFrame only.

```
public void open() {
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String quer = " select clientimg from tbl_img where imgid='" + open.getText() + "' ";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(quer);
        while (rs.next()) {
            byte[] inbytes = rs.getBytes("clientimg");
            Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(inbytes);
            ImageIcon ico = new ImageIcon(img);
            JFrame jf = new JFrame("Viewer");
            JLabel jl = new JLabel();
            jl.setSize(ico.getIconWidth(), ico.getIconHeight());
            jf.setSize(ico.getIconWidth(), ico.getIconHeight());
            jl.setIcon(ico);
            jf.add(jl);
            jf.setVisible(true);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there another way or retrieving blob back to image ? if there is feel free to modify the code for me to make it clearer to understand. I have tried I think all of possible way from google.

Comment: I strongly recommend against doing something like this.  Store that kind of file in a folder somewhere instead of in the database.

Comment: why can't I store image in database? . Can you help me either with the method that your saying?

Comment: Actually there is no general rule for which is the best approach. I have worked on a system that it was a requirement that all files (not specifically images, but also pdf and doc files) should be saved to the database. But that aside, did you tried to same the recovered bytes to a file for comparison?

Comment: i didnt. how am I going to do that?

Comment: To make it simpler to test, you could pass a byte array to the save method and use that reference to keep the bytes that are saved to the database. Then pass this byte array to the open method and compare what came from the database with what you have in memory. This is only for a specific test, I am not suggesting to change the method signatures permanently.

Comment: 1. I'd probably use `ImageIO.read(in bytes)` instead of the old toolkit, as it's much better at reporting errors loading the image. 2. You should never use `setSize(..)` in normal application code, instead just call `jf.pack()` to have all components sized to their preferred sizes (if space permits).

Comment: 3. You should run the Swing code (*not the image loading!*) on the EDT (Event Dispatcher Thread), using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(..)`. Other than that, the code looks fine to me (except it's not testable, as I don't have your DB).